# Несовместимость версии Qt и g++

Tags: linux, qtcreator, g++

После установки самой новой 32-битной версии Qt Creator для Linux в качестве компилятора была выбрана g++ 6.3.0 (новее нет в репозиториях). Во вкладках "Kits" и "Qt versions" меню "Build & Run" стоит Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 32bit, при этом на вкладке "Kits" слева от строки версии есть значок предупреждения. (Несовместимость версий Qt и g++?)

При попытке компилировать любой проект (например, с именем 123) в сообщениях появляется такое:

```
22:48:36: Running steps for project 123...
22:48:36: Starting: "/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc/bin/qmake" /home/john/123/123.pro -r -spec linux-g++-32 CONFIG+=debug
22:48:36: The process "/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc/bin/qmake" exited normally.
22:48:36: Could not start process "make" 
Error while building/deploying project 123 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
22:48:36: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Comment: может там в сообщениях немножко больше информации?

Comment: мне кажется тут не c gcc, а с make проблема то

Comment: мне кажется тут не c make, а с qmake проблема то

Comment: Очевидно установить *make*?